# XML validation, language/localization

Tags: xml, vb6, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate XML's against XSD with the DOMDocument60-object in VB6. No problem with getting the errors - so far so good.
What I'm having problem with is getting the errors in English only. We have several customers using our software, and some of them get the errors in German, Norwegian etc. I recon this is because of which language the Windows OS is using?

Is there a setting/attribute in the DOMDocument60-object so the errors are returned in a specific language/culture?

Comment: Looks like it's the display language of the OS that decides the language of the errormessages.